# End User License Costs

Tags: licenses

I need to use Salesforce Visual Workflow to create flows and expose these using custom/salesforce frontend pages to end customer.

My development team size is 10 developers who will use Enterprise Edition. 
End customer is another large external organization with 250 end users for my application.

How many licences do I require and of what kind in above scenario. Application will use data from both salesforce and my custom tables hosted on salesforce cloud.

--> As en end user, what are the costs to login into salesforce and use application (via a tabs)?

Comment: Its not very clear. What is your use case? You want to make one org talk to another and fetch its data? As for number of licenses, how many people will be logging into your customer's org, that many licenses you need. Your developers could simply have multiple login ids in the Sandbox, and just maybe one in Production to deploy the code and configuration.

Comment: @ AslamK Thanks for your comment.  As regards number of licenses, I understand that it will depend on number of people logging into my customer's org. But this kind of licence should be different from that used by my developers. If my developers will use Enterprise Edition licence for Service cloud (priced at $135/user/month), Will the end users logging into customer org also require same licence or they can use different kind of license ( as they will not customize application, just use it)

Comment: Why should it be a different license? Is it because you want to restrict the features available to them (end users)? The license they will use will depend on what kind of functionality they want to use in the org, and what kind of deal they got with Salesforce. Some opt for the Force.com license which does not have the built in CRM features. While some make do with Community licenses.

Comment: right, ok. End users need to have limited features. They are not required to customize workflows etc. but are only authorize to create data (case) and follow pre-defined approval process.    However, developers will use developer org (free) and will need 1 (one) Ent. Ed. licence to test and deploy code/new workflows, tasks, activities, reports into production. Is this correct?

Comment: Its not the license which determines whether a user can customize stuff in an org. Its his profile permissions. User A ( standard user profile ) and User B ( System Admin profile ) both need Salesforce license to access CRM features like Account, Case, Opportunity etc. But only User B can customize workflow, write code, set approval process etc, because his profile allows him to do so. And your developers can also develop in a Sandbox. This guide might help http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dev_lifecycle/salesforce_development_lifecycle.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different licenses allow access to various functionality. Typically more expensive the license the more features it offers. Refer [Pricing Editions](http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/editions-pricing.jsp) for more details. See which features your business really needs, and make your decision.

Your developers don't all need Salesforce licenses. They can develop in the Sandbox, if your org has them, and probably one System Administrator license in Production for code deployment. That should be enough.

You can also develop in a Developer org, create a package and install it in your customer's org.

Your end users will have non-system admin profiles which will allow them to use features that you develop.

You can also mix multiple license types in an org, for which you would need to talk to Salesforce.